# How to define unique foreign key combinations in sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize with postgres. I have a table that two foreign keys, one to the user and one to a promo code. How can I make enforce that only one unique pair of these foreign keys exist?

Here is how my tables are defined:

```
const promoCode = sequelize.define('promoCode',{
    code: {type: Sequelize.STRING}
});

 const user = sequelize.define('user', {
     name: {type: Sequelize.STRING}
});

const appliedPromoCode = sequelize.define('appliedPromoCode', {});

appliedPromoCode
   .belongsTo(promoCode, { foreignKey: 'promoId' });

appliedPromoCode
  .belongsTo(user, { foreignKey: 'userId' });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your migrations,
You can use [addIndex](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#addindex-tablename-attributes-options-)  or [addConstraint](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#addconstraint-tablename-attributes-options-) to specify the pair of keys as unique.